# Draw multiple vertical lines graph with OpenGL-ES on Android to realize a Spectrum real-time analyzer

Tags: android, opengl-es, plot, spectrogram

I'm new on android developing, I worked with basical opengl approaches, like particles engine or simple rotating spheres scenario on Ububntu. I'd like to realize a spectrum analyzer which getting audio signals from phone microphone, STFT processing them and plotting spectrum results on screen.

I tried to model this scenario, using about 22000 (exactly 21980) squares (each for 1 Hz) drawing and scaling each of them just on y axis according to results of STFT anayisis for each frequency component. Unfortunately this approach has failed due to the heavy computational burden of instatiating 22000 square objects which draw theselves during the callback "onDrawFrame()" of a Renderer object.

I found infos about "glDrawArrays()" and I hope this could help me but I can't understand how, using this method, I could stretch (or scaling) just om y axis each line of the LineArray I have to plot into the Renderer callback "onDrawFrame()".

Does anybody of you have some hints for me, and expecially you think this approach could be computational performant on OpenGL SE engines?

Thanks and regards, 
Leo.